# Is there a name for this auto-append design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, tables, lists

This animation best describes the pattern, whereby a new row in the table is always preserved so that the user can insert a new row without clicking a `+` button or similar:

[image: automatically appending a row]

Does it have a name? At my company we call it the 'ghost row'

Comment: Interesting question, I'm not aware of a specific name for this pattern. I think I've referred to it before as a `template row`

Comment: I don't think has a specific name for it. Why do you need? You can create your own name. Maybe, add a new item through the own item list?

Comment: @RafaelPerozin i'd like to know what to search for to see how other people have implemented it, and how to refer to it when communicating with others outside my established circle

Comment: We refer to it as "Custom row" [-__*]

Comment: Placeholder Row?

Comment: If there was a call-to-action instead of it being automatic, you would probably called it "add/new row", so I would call it the "new row".

Comment: Found a chat thread which calls it 'dynamically add row on event launch', which in this case is someone starting to type in the text field. https://community.uxmastery.com/t/dynamically-add-user-interface/5385. I have a question, when the user has entered all the data they want, is the last unfilled line still persistent and dangling?

Comment: @harshikerfuffle generally the ghost/template/custom/<insert name here> row is just UI, does not have a corresponding entry in the model

Comment: Yep, I know that after the last line is filled, the ghost does not have content, but does it still persist? Or is there some way that it disappears?

Comment: @harshikerfuffle think of it as an 'Add Row' button. if there is a natural point at which you would hide the 'Add Row' button then you can hide the ghost row too. if you would keep the 'Add Row' button visible then keep the ghost row visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular one that you have mentioned in the question do not have a name by definition as of now it seems. Anyways, from a technical side it is Adding rows dynamically with jQuery. Therefore maybe we can call it **Dynamic New Row**. [from today haha]

Please post your answers if it actually has a defined name. Then I shall remove my answer :)

Also, I'm posting this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery) link to the technically analogous question.

Comment: sounds good to me :)